# Add and customise attribute table to print composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, cartography, print-composer

I've finished a plan of farmland constituting of a polygon called 'parcels' which contains critical information for the final/printed plan. I could simply label the polygon as shown below, but there's a lot of clutter.

[image]
[image]

I've added a new field in the 'parcels' layer which associates a number to each feature, just like the ID field when creating a new shapefile. The idea for this is to label the polygon with a single number, then adding and tweaking the attribute table in print composer. Below is the look I'm trying to replicate, except I need a header such as "Number, Parcel ID, Ac, Ha"

[image]

How do I get a table as shown in the last image into the print composer? The atlas generator seems to be going in the right direction.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Keep digging in the properties of the attribute table.

The styling options are fairly robust, and if you're using the Atlas feature, you can limit the features in the table to what is shown in the Atlas, etc.

Below is an example of a set of maps we produced. The attribute table styling options allowed us to customize size, column labels, width, and visibility of features:

[image]